# Arithmetic Mean

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, average, means

Based on the definition of the arithmetic mean. AM between two non-consecutive terms $x_1$ and $x_2$ of the AP sequence is the following
$$\frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}$$

But I'm a little confused on how this formula extends to the more general cases like the following mean(or average)
$$\frac{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + ...+ x_n}{n}$$

Comment: Can you specify what is confusing about it? I think the choice of dividing the sum by the number of entries is quite intuitive...

Comment: @MattiP. seems now I got it. I've got confused AP Sequence with General AM. In AP middle term between the two terms is equivalent to AM. but I was trying to derive the general AM equation from the AP Sequence (n terms).

Answer (score 2):

In creating a mean statistic, we want to come up with a "representative" value $\mu$ for a data set. This can be done in many ways. For example, we could come up with a value that, given a set of numbers $x_i, i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$, minimizes the "total signed distance from $\mu$"
$$
D = \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu)
$$
Other definitions could use the absolute value, or squaring the quantity in parentheses. In this case it turns out that you can get $D$ to be exactly zero and I think we can be pretty happy with that. Then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu) = 0
$$
Opening the parenthesis gives us
$$
\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}_{\text{sum of all entries}} - \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n \mu}_{=n \mu} = 0
$$
and therefore
$$\mu = \frac{\text{sum of all entries}}{n}$$
In case of just two entries, the formula becomes simply
$$
\mu = \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}
$$